# "Integer expression expected error" in bc

Tags: bash, shell, unix, bc

I'm getting a "bc: integer expression expected" in this line:

```
numV=$numVtest
```

while running the script. How can I solve this error?

```
firstv=1200         #first velocity value
lastv=5000          #last velocity value
increment=200       #velocity increment
numVtest=100        #use to limit number of velocity panels
                #otherwise, use very large value (100)
#================================================
# Compute number of velocity panels

 numV='bc -l << -END
 ( ( $lastv - $firstv ) / $increment ) + 1
 END'
 if [ $numVtest -lt $numV ] ; then
 numV=$numVtest
 fi
```

Answer (score 2):

`numV` is not a number; it's a string that looks like a call to `bc`, so it cannot be used as an argument to `-lt`. I suspect you meant to use backquotes, not single quotes, in its definition.

```
numV=`bc -l << -END
...
`
```

However, it is better practice to use `$(...)` for command substitution instead of backquotes.

```
numV=$(bc -l << -END
( ( $lastv - $firstv ) / $increment ) + 1
END
)
if [ "$numVtest" -lt "$numV" ] ; then
    numV=$numVtest
fi
```

The next problem is that `-lt` only works with integers, though, while the result of `bc` could be a floating-point value. You need to do the comparison inside `bc` as well. `bc` will output a 1 if the comparison is true, and a 0 if it is false.

```
result=$(bc -l << -END
( ( $lastv - $firstv ) / $increment ) + 1 > $numVtest
END
)
if [ "$result" = 1 ] ; then
    numV=$numVtest
fi
```

Comment: note that the `test` command will still fail as `$numV` is a float, and bash can only handle integers. You'll have to cast `$numV` as an int using either string manipulation (i.e. `${numV%.*}`) or `printf`

Comment: Ugh, you're right. I missed the forest for the trees.

Comment: ... or just use the `bc` without `-l` and you will get integers... ;) e.g. `bc -l <<<"10/3"` vs `bc <<<"10/3"`

Comment: I'm assuming the OP actually wants floating-point values, or else there is no need for `bc`. (If integers are fine, I recommend SLePort's answer.)

Answer (score 1):

If the result is expected to be an integer, you don't need `bc`. You can use the `$(())` syntax instead:

```
numV=$(( ($lastv - $firstv) / $increment + 1 ))
if [ "$numVtest" -lt "$numV" ] ; then
    numV=$numVtest
fi
```

Comment: That depends on whether the result of the division is expected to be an integer (which does, however, seem likely, or at least sufficient) or a floating-point value.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, as pointed out in [chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42439132/3266847), that you just assign a string to `numV`.

You can alternatively use one less operation: if bc evaluates a boolean statement, it prints `0` or `1`, and to map that to a Bash conditional, we can wrap the bc command substitution into `(( ))`:

```
if (( $(bc -l <<< "$numVtest < ($lastv - $firstv) / $increment + 1") )); then
    numV=$numVtest
fi
```